# control arduino UNO with android app through a c# server

Tags: java, c#, android, xml, eclipse

I'm new in the site and this is my first question.
I have and Arduino UNO and i want to build an android app that communicates with a c# web server and the web server sends the data to arduino and the opposite.
Arduino does not have any shield (ethernet or wifi) is connected to the laptop with a USB.
I have some code where i need a help to fix it and make it work.

Here is the c# code:

```
/*************************SERVER*************************/ using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Text; using System.Net; using System.Net.Sockets; using System.Threading; using System.IO;

namespace SocketServer {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 18001);
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            socket.Bind(ip);
            socket.Listen(10);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");
            Socket client = socket.Accept();
            IPEndPoint clientep = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
            Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}", clientep.Address, clientep.Port);



            string welcome = "HELLO 1 FROM SERVER";
            /*read*/
            byte[] data = new byte[200];
            int receiveddata = client.Receive(data);
            Console.WriteLine("Received data from CLIENT1: {0}", System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data).Trim());


            /*write*/
            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] data2 = new byte[200];
            data2 = asen.GetBytes(welcome);
            int sentdata = client.Send(data2, data2.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent data from SERVER: {0}", welcome);


            /*read*/
            byte[] data3 = new byte[200];
            Console.WriteLine("Receiving data from CLIENT : {0}", "...");
            receiveddata = client.Receive(data3);
            Console.WriteLine("Received data from CLIENT2: {0}", System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data3).Trim());

            /*write*/
            byte[] data4 = new byte[200];
            data4 = asen.GetBytes("HELLO 2 FROM SERVER");
            sentdata = client.Send(data4, data4.Length, SocketFlags.None);

            client.Close();
            socket.Close();


            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from {0}", clientep.Address);



            Console.ReadLine();
        }//main

    } }
```

and here is the android app code (I'm new in the android development):
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.smarthomefinal;

import eneter.messaging.diagnostic.EneterTrace;
import eneter.messaging.endpoints.typedmessages.*;
import eneter.messaging.messagingsystems.messagingsystembase.*;
import eneter.messaging.messagingsystems.tcpmessagingsystem.TcpMessagingSystemFactory;
import eneter.net.system.EventHandler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import android.R;
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    // Request message type
    // The message must have the same name as declared in the service.
    // Also, if the message is the inner class, then it must be static.
    public static class MyRequest
    {
        public String Text;
    }

    // Response message type
    // The message must have the same name as declared in the service.
    // Also, if the message is the inner class, then it must be static.
    public static class MyResponse
    {
        public int Length;
    }

    // UI controls
    private Handler myRefresh = new Handler();
    private EditText myMessageTextEditText;
    private EditText myResponseEditText;
    private Button mySendRequestBtn;


    // Sender sending MyRequest and as a response receiving MyResponse.
    private IDuplexTypedMessageSender<MyResponse, MyRequest> mySender;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get UI widgets.
        myMessageTextEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageTextEditText);
        myResponseEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageLengthEditText);
        mySendRequestBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendRequestBtn);

        // Subscribe to handle the button click.
        mySendRequestBtn.setOnClickListener(myOnSendRequestClickHandler);

        // Open the connection in another thread.
        // Note: From Android 3.1 (Honeycomb) or higher
        //       it is not possible to open TCP connection
        //       from the main thread.
        Thread anOpenConnectionThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        openConnection();
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        EneterTrace.error("Open connection failed.", err);
                    }
                }
            });
        anOpenConnectionThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // Stop listening to response messages.
        mySender.detachDuplexOutputChannel();

        super.onDestroy();
    } 

    private void openConnection() throws Exception
    {
        // Create sender sending MyRequest and as a response receiving MyResponse
        IDuplexTypedMessagesFactory aSenderFactory =
           new DuplexTypedMessagesFactory();
        mySender = aSenderFactory.createDuplexTypedMessageSender(MyResponse.class, MyRequest.class);

        // Subscribe to receive response messages.
        mySender.responseReceived().subscribe(myOnResponseHandler);

        // Create TCP messaging for the communication.
        // Note: 10.0.2.2 is a special alias to the loopback (127.0.0.1)
        //       on the development machine
        IMessagingSystemFactory aMessaging = new TcpMessagingSystemFactory();
        IDuplexOutputChannel anOutputChannel = 
           aMessaging.createDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://10.0.2.2:8060/");

        // Attach the output channel to the sender and be able to send
        // messages and receive responses.
        mySender.attachDuplexOutputChannel(anOutputChannel);
    }

    private void onSendRequest(View v)
    {
        // Create the request message.
        MyRequest aRequestMsg = new MyRequest();
        aRequestMsg.Text = myMessageTextEditText.getText().toString();

        // Send the request message.
        try
        {
            mySender.sendRequestMessage(aRequestMsg);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            EneterTrace.error("Sending the message failed.", err);
        }
    }

    private void onResponseReceived(Object sender, final TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse> e)
    {
        // Display the result - returned number of characters.
        // Note: Marshal displaying to the correct UI thread.
        myRefresh.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    myResponseEditText.setText(Integer.toString(e.getResponseMessage().Length));
                }
            });
    }

    private EventHandler<TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse>> myOnResponseHandler

         = new EventHandler<TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Object sender,
                            TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse> e)
        {
            onResponseReceived(sender, e);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener myOnSendRequestClickHandler = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            onSendRequest(v);
        }
    };
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.client"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Waht exactly is your problem? I cannot see any code communicating with the arduino.

Comment: Just in case: Although the arduino is connectes via USB, you have to "talk" via a COM port to it.

Comment: Hello and thanks for ur reply.
Well the arduino sketch is ok my problem is to send data from the android app to a web server and the web server(same  pc where the arduino is connected) send those data to arduino(turn on the LED for example).

Answer (score 2):

You are still a bit far from your goal. I suggest you divide your solution into a few steps:

1) Download and install http://sourceforge.net/projects/sockettest/.
SocketTest is a very useful java program that allows you to send/receive TCP/UDP messages.

2) With the aid of SocketTest expand your C# server (not web server, there is a difference) to receive text messages from the network and send commands to the Arduino through the appropriate COM port (remember that the Arduino will appear as a serial device when attached through the USB interface).

3) Once your C# server and Arduino sketch are working properly, modify your Android code so that it sends the messages to which your C# program can respond.

I hope this points you in the right direction.